# Binomial coefficient with a twist

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab

Right now, to enumerate all k=4 combinations among the set

```
Set = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8]
```

I use the prebuilt Matlab function nchoosek that compute the binomial coefficients. The number of combinations of n things taken k at a time is computed by n!/((n–k)! k!).

Now, imagine that I have a set of data containing n = 8 elements:

```
Set = [1.A; 2.B; 3.C; 4.D; 5.B; 6.D; 7.C; 8.A]
```

I want to enumerate all the combinations of 4 *integers* in "Set", but with a twist: I must have only one element with the same *letter* in any combination (the order doesn't matter). For example:

[1.A; 2.B; 6.D; 7.C] would be a valid combination, but not [1.A; 2.B; 6.D; 8.A].

Having [1.A; 2.B; 6.D; 7.C], I must still generate the combination [8.A; 2.B; 6.D; 7.C]

Instead of having to generate 70 combinations, since there are 2 occurrences of A, B, C and D, I only have to generate 2*2*2*2 = 16 combinations. The 70-16 = 54 other combinations are irrelevant to my problem and I would rather not generate them since it becomes increasingly computationally expansive. For the moment, I generate the 70 combinations, then use some logic to remove the all the non relevant combinations.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a name for such a type of combinations? (Could help me to search for info and better understand the problem)
2. Is there some existing algorithm allowing to compute that? In Matlab or C++. Please, if it is full of reg ex, a bit of explanations would be welcome...

Comment: So you are looking to calculate how many sets exist? Or are you looking to generate the sets for further processing?

Comment: I am looking for both, but mainly to generate all the sets for further processing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general recursive (iterative if stacked) algorithm:

```
combs(index,multiset,k,result):
  if length of result == k:
    output result
    return
  if length of result + length of multiset - index < k:
    return
  for j in multiset[index]:
    combs(index + 1,multiset,k,result with multiset[index][j] added)
  combs(index + 1,multiset,k,result)
```

JavaScript example:

```js
function combs(i,multiset,k,result){
  if (result.length == k){
    console.log(result);
    return;
  }
  if (result.length + multiset.length - i < k)
    return;
  for (var j=0; j<multiset[i].length; j++){
    _result = result.slice();
    _result.push(multiset[i][j]);
    combs(i + 1,multiset,k,_result);
  }
  combs(i + 1,multiset,k,result);
}

combs(0,[["1.A","8.A"],["2.B","5.B"],["3.C","7.C"],["4.D","6.D"]],4,[]);
```

Comment: Is there a non recursive general algorithm for this?

Comment: @Doombot one way could be to stack the calls so inside the function, you first call `myCurrentParameters  = stack.pop()`, do something with `myCurrentParameters` and then instead of calling `myFunction(param1,param2,param3...)` push the next configuration/s to the stack `stack.push(param1,param2,param3...)`. You can enumerate array indexes/pointers in your stacked parameters, rather than actual element lists, to make it as efficient as possible. I can't think of a straightforward way to iterate those combinations right now, although that sounds interesting.

Comment: Ok I was trying to find a straightforward way to solve it, since I am not that great with recursive functions in Matlab. But I fear it will not be possible,  anyway not possible without hardcoding stuff such as the number of letters (A,B,C,D - 4 letters, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Transform you set to the form

```
[A[1, 8], B[2,5], C[3,7], D[4,6]]
```

Generate base combinations by letter key - here is only one (C(4,4)) base combination (A,B,C,D) and expand combinations with number subkeys (for example, with recursive approach)

Answer (score 1):

Your twist adds a constraint to the problem. As far as I know there is no special name for this new problem, it is just a combinatorics problem like any other.

Notice that what you have ultimately done is add choices for each possible "slot" in the result set. The underlying assumption for the regular choose formula is that a given item can be either in the set, or not in the set. Notice that for each group A, B, C, and D, either

1. A *single* integer of that type is in the result set,

OR

2. An integer of that type is *not in the set at all*

Thus selecting which *types* of integers will be in the result set is the analog of selecting the actual *integers* that were in the result set of the original problem! Once we select which types of integers are in the result set, we can just make any choice for which integer of each type we will put into the set.

In your case, if we must choose 4 types to put into the set then the number of ways to do that is 4 choose 4 = 1 (A,B,C,D). For type A there are 2 options, type B there are 2 options, type C there are 2 options and type D there are 2 options, so there are 2*2*2*2=16 sets to choose :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just the standard C(N, K) with a uniquness check. The below code is JavaScript but converting it to C++ shouldn't be too difficult.

```
function nchoosekUnique(arr, k, combo, result) {
  if(combo.length === k) {
    result.push(combo);
    return result;
  }
  for(var i=0; i < arr.length - k; i++) {
    // UNIQUE CHECK
    var unique = true;
    for(var u=0; u<combo.length; u++) {
      if(combo[u][1] == arr[i][1]) { 
        unique = false; 
        continue; 
      }
    }
    //
    if(unique === true) {
      var comboCpy = combo.slice(0);
      var arrCpy = arr.slice(0);
      comboCpy[comboCpy.length] = arrCpy.splice(i, 1)[0];
      nchoosekUnique(arrCpy, k, comboCpy, result);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var arr = [[1,"A"], [2,"B"], [3,"C"], [4,"D"], [5,"B"], [6,"D"], [7,"C"], [8,"A"]];
JSON.stringify(nchoosekUnique(arr, 4, [], []), null, '\t');
```

**note** If you're K's are very large you may want to use a Set (HashSet) implementation for the combo variable instead of just an array.